# Handle nested Maybes [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I have a function that requires the handling of two Maybes. This is an extremely naive implementation:

```
go :: IO (Maybe Int)
go = do
    res1 <- firstFunction
    case res1 of
      Nothing -> return Nothing
      Just a  -> do
        res2 <- secondFunction a
          case res2 of
            Nothing -> return Nothing
            Just b  -> return b
```

How could I structure this so that I can use the result `a` of the `firstFunction` in my `secondFunction`?

Comment: Not wanting to give the answer away, have you learned about functors yet?

Comment: What are the types of `firstFunction` and `secondFunction`? From your definition of `go` they should be `firstFunction :: IO (Maybe Int)` and `secondFunction :: Int -> Maybe (Maybe Int)`?

Comment: @Lee, that's correct.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, I haven't learned about functors yet, no.

Comment: Do you just want to convert the `Maybe (Maybe Int)` into a `Maybe Int`? You can use `join` and replace your last `case` expression with `return (join res2)`.

Comment: Do you know what monad transformers (e.g., `MaybeT`) are?

Comment: @timothyylim Then it's time you *learned* about functors. They aren't some advanced concept that you should ignore until you've mastered the basics; they *are* one of the basics.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MaybeT IO a` instead of `IO (Maybe a)`. Then:

```
firstFunction :: MaybeT IO X
firstFunction = undefined -- ...
secondFunction :: X -> MaybeT IO Int
secondFunction = undefined -- ...

go :: IO (Maybe Int)
go = do
    a <- firstFunction
    secondFunction a

-- OR

go = firstFunction >>= secondFunction
```

You may use these two halves of an isomorphism to convert between the two types:

```
MaybeT :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

To reduce the total number of uses of them, I recommend pushing the former as deep into the leaves of your computation as you can, and lifting the latter as far out as you can. You may also like these actions for defining leaf computations:

```
lift :: IO a -> MaybeT IO a
liftIO :: IO a -> MaybeT IO a
empty :: MaybeT IO a -- for when you want a Nothing
pure :: a -> MaybeT IO a -- for when you want a Just
maybe empty pure :: Maybe a -> MaybeT IO a
```